# FontAwesome 5 doesn't show in Chrome when css-called, but shows in Safari

Tags: google-chrome, safari, font-awesome

On the site <www.lichaamengeest.be> there is use of FontAwesome 5.15.4. All icons show well, except for the ones that are called from the css, like "\f104", "\f0dd", "\f106" and "\f105" (small arrow "angle" left, right, up and down).

Two questions:

- why do other icons show but not the arrows
- why do they all show in Safari

(no use of AdBlock)

This is the css code for the 8 links in the footer, where I would like to show a right angle before the link:

```
#footer .footer-links li:before {
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
font-size: 20px;
content: "\f105";
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: -2px;
padding: 0 7px 0 0;
color: #ccc;
}
```

This is in the header:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css

And also all the icons are saved on the server.
Is the css code wrong so it doesn't call the icons to show? But then why does it show in Safari?